# Using standart sql, how to convert timestamp to unix time?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp, unix-timestamp

In mysql, one can do this in order to compare 2 timestamp :

```
where UNIX_TIMESTAMP(transaction.closed_on)<UNIX_TIMESTAMP(transaction.opened_on)...
```

What’s the equivalent function for Google bigquery ?

Comment: Subtract? With the the less-than operator?

Comment: @CaiusJard I wanted to write compare sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... to subtract 2 timestamp : ...

you can use `TIMESTAMP_DIFF(closed_on, opened_on, SECOND)` for BigQuery Standard SQL

> to compare in WHERE clause

WHERE closed_on < opened_on

> finally, to convert timestamp to unix time ...

Use UNIX_SECONDS() function

Answer (score 0):

It is called `UNIX_SECONDS`:

```
select UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 15:30:00")) - UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP("2008-11-25 15:30:00"))
```